# Chaining compound assignment operators in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, side-effects, compound-assignment

In C#,

```
string s = "abc";
s += (s += s);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

writes `abcabcabc` (http://ideone.com/pFNFX2).  This is fine, because the C# specification explicitly says in section 7.16.2 that

> the operation is evaluated as x = x op y, except that x is evaluated only once.

However, in reading the description of the compound assignment operator in section 11.3.2 of the ECMAScript 5.1 Language Specification, I see no such "only once" qualifier in the semantics of this operator.  Instead, all I see is:

> 1. Let lref be the result of evaluating LeftHandSideExpression.
> 2. Let lval be GetValue(lref).
> 3. Let rref be the result of evaluating AssignmentExpression.
> 4. Let rval be GetValue(rref).
> 5. Let r be the result of applying operator @ to lval and rval.
> 6. Throw a SyntaxError exception if the following conditions are all true: (snipped)
> 7. Call PutValue(lref, r).
> 8. Return r.

Therefore, it would appear (to me, anyway) that the following JavaScript code

```
var s = "abc";
s += (s += s);
alert(s);
```

would alert `abcabcabcabc` (because of the PutValue on line 7 in the parenthesized expression), but, in Chrome 22 anyway, it alerts `abcabcabc`.

So my question is:  Am I misreading the specification, or is Chrome (V8 perhaps?) doing its own thing off-spec, so to speak?

Comment: Have you tested in any other browser to see if this behavior is the same?

Comment: If you break down what `s += (s += s);` actually is, it becomes `s = s + (s + s);` and I think that's simple enough to say that the result should be "abcabcabc"

Comment: _Why_ is it rewritten that way?  Why do we not rewrite and completely evaluate the right-hand side first and ... OH ... duh! I think you have the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I think if you break open the operation, you have:

```
s += (s += s);

s = s + (s += s);
s = s + (s = s + s);    // Can't actually have the "s = " part, it's really just "s + s"
s = s + (s + s);
s = s + s + s;
```

Which means the result should be "abcabcabc".

Comment: That's it.  The key is line 2 in the semantics.  It evaluates s into lval before we even go look at the right hand side.  You've reflected that nicely in your breakdown.